# Unity - Drag and Drop prefab cursor sync

Tags: c#, user-interface, mouseevent, unity3d-editor

Simple drag and drop puzzle game, I have a parent canvas a child background image and the puzzle slots are instantiated as children under that parent image. I thought I could just use `mouseToWorldPosition` as a started doing this but I also have the unity player controller in here which was causing some strange behaviour with the camera. So I opted for using an ondrag function with rect transforms which almost works.

The problem is a cursor disparity as i drag my cursor  moving the red skull (puzzle piece) it starts off in the correct position but then quickly increments position out of sync with the cursor (denoted by the cross) and responds in a radius to the cursor. The rest of the functionality is fine and I suspect its something to do with the rect transforms(which all have the normal 0.5 centered pivots). Any help would be great!
[image: cursor disparity] [image: editor]

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

    public class PuzzlePiece : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IDragHandler
    {
        #region ----------------------------------- variables -----------------------------------
        [SerializeField] private AudioSource _source; 
        [SerializeField] private AudioClip _pickupClip, _dropClip;
        [SerializeField] private Image _image;
        private bool _dragging, _placed;  
        private Vector2 _originalPosition;  
        private RectTransform _rectTransform;
        private RectTransform _canvasRectTransform;
        private PuzzleSlot _slot;

        #endregion

        #region ----------------------------------- built in functions -----------------------------------
        void Start()
        {
            _originalPosition = transform.position;
            _rectTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
            _canvasRectTransform = transform.parent.parent.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        }
        void Update()
        {
            if (_placed) return;
        }
        
        #endregion
        
        #region ----------------------------------- private functions -----------------------------------

        private Vector2 ClampPosition(Vector2 position)
        {
            Vector2 minPosition = _canvasRectTransform.rect.min - _rectTransform.rect.min;
            Vector2 maxPosition = _canvasRectTransform.rect.max - _rectTransform.rect.max;
            return new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp(position.x, minPosition.x, maxPosition.x), Mathf.Clamp(position.y, minPosition.y, maxPosition.y));
        }

        #endregion
        #region ----------------------------------- public functions -----------------------------------
        public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            _dragging = true;
            _source.PlayOneShot(_pickupClip);
            _originalPosition = _rectTransform.anchoredPosition;
        }


        public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            Vector2 currentPosition = _rectTransform.anchoredPosition + eventData.delta;
            Vector2 clampedPosition = ClampPosition(currentPosition);
            _rectTransform.anchoredPosition = clampedPosition;
        }

        public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            float distance = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, _slot.transform.position);
            if (distance < 40)
            {
                Debug.Log("matched " + distance);
                transform.position = _slot.transform.position;
                _slot.Placed();
                _placed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("not matched " + distance);
                _rectTransform.anchoredPosition = _originalPosition;
                _dragging = false;
                _source.PlayOneShot(_dropClip);
            }
        }

        public void Init(PuzzleSlot slot)
        {
            _image = slot._image;
            _slot = slot;

        }
        #endregion

}
```

Comment: the scale of the parent canvas was off was the problem messing with the rect transform, set it to 2,2,1 and all was well, hopefully helps somebody out